# Infinite scroll in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I use [this](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-21-pagination-system-with-infinite-scroll/43) article to create infinite scroll and this is my client and server code:

```
// server-side
Meteor.publish('getContactUsMessages', function(limit) {
    if (limit > ContactUsMessages.find().count()) {
        limit = 0;
    }

    return ContactUsMessages.find({ }, { limit: limit });
});

// client-side
incrementLimit = function(inc) {
    inc = inc || 2;
    newLimit = Session.get('limit') + inc;
    Session.set('limit', newLimit);
};
```

When I increase the limit of the find, is it going to re-fetch all the data, including the data that you already had, or does it fetch only the additional data that is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the new data. You can confirm this for yourself by using your browser's inspector to look at the network traffic that occurs when you increase the limit.

Comment: I try using browser network tool but no log shown to me.

Comment: You have to examine websockets with the inspector. That's where updates to collections come through.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I saw all data at first but after remove autopublish package all things fixed.